# OpenGL 3D Model Transparency Issues

Tags: opengl, textures, blender

I've recently imported a 3D model made in Blender to OpenGL using Assimp. While all of the geometry is fine, I noticed that some transparent planes (the Star) are not rendering correctly in OpenGL.

It seems that OpenGL senses that the plane is transparent, and then forgets to draw any of the model behind it.  As I rotate the view, the "transparent" part of the plane (Star) constantly changes texture.

In addition, the model's Staff she's holding in her right hand has a transparency applied from the texture as well. When it intersects over her leg, it seems to be the same effect as the Star, which almost looks like some messed up backface culling.

For reference, I've made sure that:

- Backface culling is disabled
- The PNG textures have transparent backgrounds
- Alpha blending is turned on

Also the first and third pictures are from the Assimp Model Viewer, but the same result happens in my OpenGL program.

My OpenGL texture is loaded by:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, surface->w, surface->h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, surface->pixels);
```

And my fragment shader looks like:

```
#version 130

in vec2 texcoord;
uniform sampler2D textureSample;

void main()
{
    gl_FragData[0] = texture(textureSample, texcoord).aaaa * texture(textureSample, texcoord);
}
```

And my blending / depth is:

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
```

Any idea what could be the problem?

[image: View in Assimp Model Viewer]

[image: View in Blender]

[image: View of transparent staff]

Comment: Transparency is order-dependent, so you need to render opaque surfaces first, and then transparent surfaces in back-to-front order. Also see [the OpenGL FAQ on transparency](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/transparency.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I did some research and it looks like there's a trick where you disabled depth buffer writes on transparent objects (glDepthMask(GL_FALSE)) and draw without sorting.

This is obviously a lot faster than sorting every transparent face. Would you know any restrictions with this technique?

Comment: @lzman: yeah: it produces wrong results.